# Why is the number '7' printed after my string in C?

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I need to define the characters in an array and print the string...But it always prints as string7 (in this case, test7)...What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char a[]={'t','e','s','t'};
    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **Why this behavior?**

Because you did not `\0` terminate your array, so what you get is **Undefined behavior**.

> **What possibly happens behind the scenes ?**

The `printf` tries to print the string till it encounters a `\0` and in your case the string was never `\0` terminated so it prints randomly till it encounters a `\0`.
Note that reading beyond the bounds of allocated memory is Undefined behavior so technically this is a UB.

> **What you need to do to solve the problem?**

You need:

```
char a[]={'t','e','s','t',`\0`};
```

or

```
char a[]="test";
```

Comment: Ah...Thank you.  For some reason I thought that \0 was automatically appended to the end of a character array.

Answer (score 2):

Because your "string", or `char[]`, is not null-terminated (i.e. terminated by `\0`).

then, `printf("%s", a);` will attempt to print every character starting from the start of `a` and keep printing until it sees until it sees a `\0`.

That `\0` is outside your array, and depends on the initial state of the memory of your program, which you pretty much don't have control.

to fix this, use

```
char a[]={'t','e','s','t','\0'};
```

Answer (score 2):

The string you printing must be null terminated...so your string declaration should be,

```
char a[]={'t','e','s','t', '\0'};
```

Comment: (Nit: If the object is *not* null-terminated then it is *not* a string.)

Comment: Nit's Nit: Not all strings must be null terminated, for example [PStrings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29#Length-prefixed)